# How to mitigate the hierarchical error propagation in tree-structured classification

Tags: machine-learning, trees, modelling, svm

Suppose we have a multi-class classification problem, where the number of classes $K \geq 3$

We use a tree structure of multiple SVMs to divide and conquer the problem, with one example in the figure below.

[image: example tree structure]

Generally, in this kind of hierarchical classification, if a sample is wrongly classified in an upper layer, it is less likely to be corrected again in lower layers.

My question: Is there any strategy to mitigate such hierarchical error propagation in tree-structured classification?

Much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure I accept the premise of the problem you are trying to solve. If an object is misclassified in a high level, then it is _certainly_ misclassified in a lower level: if classifying a book as a food is wrong, then classifying a book as a fruit is certainly wrong, whereas you suggest that such misclassification may be corrected in lower levels. Does your hierarchical relation have the property _all fruits are food_, or is the relationship more fuzzy than that?

Comment: Why do you limit yourself to tree-structured classification?  If you don't like the disadvantages of tree-structure classification, the obvious solution is to look at a different method of doing multi-class classification (there are others that don't use a tree structure).  What requirement do you have, that a non-tree-structured classification fails to meet?